# Is there a way to switch connected device of apple bluetooth keyboard via keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, bluetooth

I'm wondering if it's possible, with an apple bluetooth keyboard, to switch devices that the keyboard connects to. Let me give an example, for instance if I have a macbook pro and my android cellphone both with bluetooth enabled, would it be possible to add a macro to switch the input from typing on my computer to typing on my phone? I'm able to control my phone with my apple keyboard, that I've already checked and was successful, I just want an easy way to switch between the two using the same keyboard.

Thanks

Comment: I doubt it is possible. Bluetooth requires pairing and you need keyboards that are custom designed to pair with multiple devices (usually have a physical switch for selection).

Comment: I should also note that my bluetooth keyboard magically works when switching OS with Bootcamp. No repeated pairing needed. I was not expecting it to work. But it is not the same scenario as yours.